# HttpClient static with new

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have read a lot on this but still confused. Below is how I am using HttpClient so that it can be reused:

```
private static HttpClient client;

    public ClientClass()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }
```

What I don't understand is that even though it is static, I am still creating a new instance on every controller call. Only if I make several HttpClient calls within the same method will it be reused, but other than that it will always create a new instance with each web request.

Should one HttpClient instance be reused through multiple web requests, and if so how do I do that since the way I am doing it creates a new instance on every api call?

Also, is there a difference if I do:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public ClientClass() {}
```

Comment: Creating the new instance each time defeats the purpose of having the static variable

Comment: Create a global variable that can be accessed instead of creating one within a method

Comment: @Nkosi so is there an example of the right way?  The way I showed is how every article says to do it.

Comment: What articles did you find that use the instance constructor (rather than a static constructor)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where you were reading that pointed you towards your current implementation, especially since you are saying multiple sources gave you this idea.

My assumption is that you misread these sources as showing you a normal consturctor, instead of a static one?

As Jawad pointed out, you are creating a new instance each time which completely defeats the purpose of having the static variable.

As stated on MSDN. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

```
class ClientClass 
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client;
    static ClientClass() 
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

The key here is that you're using a static constructor. So the object is only created once, and not every time you create an instance of the class, as you suspected.

If you want to read more about static constructors you can do so here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of using static instance of `HttpClient` directly. Singleton or static instance of `HttpClient` doesn't respect DNS changes. More details is in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224).

Comment: .net core specific though, no?

Comment: I am not using .net core. I tried installing dependency injection package and got an instance of  HttpClientFactory. The build worked with no errors but the web app went crazy with errors.

Comment: @MattEvans `IHttpClientFactory` is defined in [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) nuget package. It targets to [.NET Standard 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) (see official [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.csproj)). In particular it means that you may use this factory abstraction from .NET Framework 4.6.1 also.
Thus, you can use `IHttpClientFactory` from .NET Framework 4.6.1+, and .NET Core 2.0+.